# Cross compiling a python script on windows into linux executable

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, cross-compiling

I've created a program using Python on Windows. How do you turn it into Linux executable? To be specific Linux Ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: Why do you need to make it an executable? Can't you just use the plain Python .py file?

Comment: Because if I use a plain .py file, the computer I run the program on would have to have python and the libraries I use installed. While python should not be a problem because Ubuntu have python with it, the libraries will become problem since I use wx, which is not bundled in Ubuntu's release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tendou,

Since I usually develop on a Linux machine, when I need a windows version I often use cx_freeze to make windows binaries, but I also used it to make Linux binaries and it works pretty well (it is multiplatform, something py2exe is not). Like Eli said above, it doesn't really compile, but just bundles the interpreter, byte compiled code and needed libraries into an executable, but you'll get what you want (running on a machine without python pre-installed).

After having installed cx_freeze on a Linux machine, you can try it out with something simple, like this dummy code, which i saved as *test.py*:

```
import time

for i in range(10):
  print i
  time.sleep(1)
```

Then run *cxfreeze* to make the binary. The output will look like this:

```
$ cxfreeze test.py 
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cx_Freeze/bases/Console -> /home/claudio/dist/test
copying /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0 -> /home/claudio/dist/libpython2.6.so.1.0
writing zip file /home/claudio/dist/test

  Name                      File
  ----                      ----
m StringIO                  
m UserDict                  
m __builtin__               
m __main__                  test.py
m _abcoll                   
m _codecs                   
m _codecs_cn                /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_codecs_cn.so
m _codecs_hk                /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_codecs_hk.so
m _codecs_iso2022           /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_codecs_iso2022.so
m _codecs_jp                /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_codecs_jp.so
m _codecs_kr                /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_codecs_kr.so
m _codecs_tw                /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_codecs_tw.so
m _functools                /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_functools.so
m _locale                   /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_locale.so
m _multibytecodec           /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_multibytecodec.so
m _sre                      
m _strptime                 /usr/lib/python2.6/_strptime.py
m _struct                   /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_struct.so
m _warnings                 
m abc                       
m array                     /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/array.so
m base64                    
m binascii                  /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/binascii.so
m bz2                       /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/bz2.so
m cStringIO                 /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so
m calendar                  /usr/lib/python2.6/calendar.py
m codecs                    
m copy                      
m copy_reg                  
m cx_Freeze__init__         /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py
m datetime                  /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/datetime.so
m dummy_thread              /usr/lib/python2.6/dummy_thread.py
P encodings                 
m encodings.aliases         
m encodings.ascii           
m encodings.base64_codec    
m encodings.big5            
m encodings.big5hkscs       
m encodings.bz2_codec       
m encodings.charmap         
m encodings.cp037           
m encodings.cp1006          
m encodings.cp1026          
m encodings.cp1140          
m encodings.cp1250          
m encodings.cp1251          
m encodings.cp1252          
m encodings.cp1253          
m encodings.cp1254          
m encodings.cp1255          
m encodings.cp1256          
m encodings.cp1257          
m encodings.cp1258          
m encodings.cp424           
m encodings.cp437           
m encodings.cp500           
m encodings.cp737           
m encodings.cp775           
m encodings.cp850           
m encodings.cp852           
m encodings.cp855           
m encodings.cp856           
m encodings.cp857           
m encodings.cp860           
m encodings.cp861           
m encodings.cp862           
m encodings.cp863           
m encodings.cp864           
m encodings.cp865           
m encodings.cp866           
m encodings.cp869           
m encodings.cp874           
m encodings.cp875           
m encodings.cp932           
m encodings.cp949           
m encodings.cp950           
m encodings.euc_jis_2004    
m encodings.euc_jisx0213    
m encodings.euc_jp          
m encodings.euc_kr          
m encodings.gb18030         
m encodings.gb2312          
m encodings.gbk             
m encodings.hex_codec       
m encodings.hp_roman8       
m encodings.hz              
m encodings.idna            
m encodings.iso2022_jp      
m encodings.iso2022_jp_1    
m encodings.iso2022_jp_2    
m encodings.iso2022_jp_2004 
m encodings.iso2022_jp_3    
m encodings.iso2022_jp_ext  
m encodings.iso2022_kr      
m encodings.iso8859_1       
m encodings.iso8859_10      
m encodings.iso8859_11      
m encodings.iso8859_13      
m encodings.iso8859_14      
m encodings.iso8859_15      
m encodings.iso8859_16      
m encodings.iso8859_2       
m encodings.iso8859_3       
m encodings.iso8859_4       
m encodings.iso8859_5       
m encodings.iso8859_6       
m encodings.iso8859_7       
m encodings.iso8859_8       
m encodings.iso8859_9       
m encodings.johab           
m encodings.koi8_r          
m encodings.koi8_u          
m encodings.latin_1         
m encodings.mac_arabic      
m encodings.mac_centeuro    
m encodings.mac_croatian    
m encodings.mac_cyrillic    
m encodings.mac_farsi       
m encodings.mac_greek       
m encodings.mac_iceland     
m encodings.mac_latin2      
m encodings.mac_roman       
m encodings.mac_romanian    
m encodings.mac_turkish     
m encodings.mbcs            
m encodings.palmos          
m encodings.ptcp154         
m encodings.punycode        
m encodings.quopri_codec    
m encodings.raw_unicode_escape 
m encodings.rot_13          
m encodings.shift_jis       
m encodings.shift_jis_2004  
m encodings.shift_jisx0213  
m encodings.string_escape   
m encodings.tis_620         
m encodings.undefined       
m encodings.unicode_escape  
m encodings.unicode_internal 
m encodings.utf_16          
m encodings.utf_16_be       
m encodings.utf_16_le       
m encodings.utf_32          
m encodings.utf_32_be       
m encodings.utf_32_le       
m encodings.utf_7           
m encodings.utf_8           
m encodings.utf_8_sig       
m encodings.uu_codec        
m encodings.zlib_codec      
m errno                     
m functools                 /usr/lib/python2.6/functools.py
m genericpath               
m gettext                   /usr/lib/python2.6/gettext.py
m imp                       
m itertools                 /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/itertools.so
m linecache                 
m locale                    /usr/lib/python2.6/locale.py
m operator                  /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/operator.so
m optparse                  /usr/lib/python2.6/optparse.py
m os                        
m posix                     
m posixpath                 
m pwd                       
m quopri                    
m re                        /usr/lib/python2.6/re.py
m repr                      
m sre_compile               /usr/lib/python2.6/sre_compile.py
m sre_constants             /usr/lib/python2.6/sre_constants.py
m sre_parse                 /usr/lib/python2.6/sre_parse.py
m stat                      
m string                    /usr/lib/python2.6/string.py
m stringprep                
m strop                     /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/strop.so
m struct                    
m sys                       
m textwrap                  /usr/lib/python2.6/textwrap.py
m thread                    
m time                      /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/time.so
m token                     /usr/lib/python2.6/token.py
m tokenize                  /usr/lib/python2.6/tokenize.py
m traceback                 
m types                     
m unicodedata               /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so
m warnings                  
m zipimport                 
m zlib                      /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/zlib.so

copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_codecs_cn.so -> /home/claudio/dist/_codecs_cn.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_codecs_hk.so -> /home/claudio/dist/_codecs_hk.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_codecs_iso2022.so -> /home/claudio/dist/_codecs_iso2022.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_codecs_jp.so -> /home/claudio/dist/_codecs_jp.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_codecs_kr.so -> /home/claudio/dist/_codecs_kr.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_codecs_tw.so -> /home/claudio/dist/_codecs_tw.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_functools.so -> /home/claudio/dist/_functools.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_locale.so -> /home/claudio/dist/_locale.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_multibytecodec.so -> /home/claudio/dist/_multibytecodec.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_struct.so -> /home/claudio/dist/_struct.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/array.so -> /home/claudio/dist/array.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/binascii.so -> /home/claudio/dist/binascii.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/bz2.so -> /home/claudio/dist/bz2.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so -> /home/claudio/dist/cStringIO.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/datetime.so -> /home/claudio/dist/datetime.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/itertools.so -> /home/claudio/dist/itertools.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/operator.so -> /home/claudio/dist/operator.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/strop.so -> /home/claudio/dist/strop.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/time.so -> /home/claudio/dist/time.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so -> /home/claudio/dist/unicodedata.so
copying /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/zlib.so -> /home/claudio/dist/zlib.so
```

Note that with bigger projects you might get "Missing modules" errors. If you are sure they are installed, you can manually point them to cx_freeze using the *--include-modules* switch. See *cxfreeze --help* for the full help.

You can also make a *setup.py* file which makes "cxfreezing" resemble the way we usually install python packages, instead of doing it directly from the command line. This article even does that for a **wxPython** project, which might be similar to yours:
[A cx_Freeze Tutorial – Build a Binary Series!](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/08/12/a-cx_freeze-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/)

Comment: Did you find the answer useful @Tendou Kishi? Please consider voting it up if you did.. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Some projects that can help you do that are [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) and [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

Do note that what they all do is not "compiling" in the classic sense. Rather, they can bundle the Python interpreter with all the libraries required for your program into a single executable.

Comment: I think py2exe is out. www.py2exe.org says that py2exe is a Python Distutils extension which converts Python scripts into executable Windows programs, able to run without requiring a Python installation. What I need to make is Linux executable, not Windows. I'll try the other 2 tomorrow as it is late night in my time region.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience deploying applications on Linux - but can't you add dependencies when you package the software for `apt-get`?  I install packages that bring in other libraries all the time.  Seems like you could do this for wx.