# how to run python on linux whic compile on windows pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I build my python app on windows with pycharm. My app have many libraries.

How to export it to run on linux ?

I have **venv** folder on windows which include libraries.

thanks in advance

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733542/how-to-use-the-same-python-virtualenv-on-both-windows-and-linux

Comment: I want to now can I make like exe or jar file with libraries and directly run it on linux

Comment: If those same libraries are installed on the Linux machine, native Python code will run. (Except when you used platform-dependent code, of course – `win32com` and the like).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross compiling a python script on windows into linux executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372216/cross-compiling-a-python-script-on-windows-into-linux-executable)

Comment: you can copy all code to Linux and you can use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to create list with needed modules. And you can install them using `pip install -r requirements.txt`. File `.exe` will not run on Linux if you don't have installed WINE (WIndows emulator). You may try to use cx_freeze to create autorunning zip file but it may have to use it on LInux to create version for Linux.